# Call the same overridden method one after another in multiple classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have one base class `C1` that provides a default implementation of a couple of methods as `C2` and a lot of custom implementations `Cx` (+20) which looks like this:

```cs
abstract class C1
{
    public abstract void M1();
}

abstract class C2 : C1
{
    // other overridden members ...

    // M1(); has no default implementation yet.
}

class Cx : C2
{
    public override void M1()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to chain `C2.M1` and `Cx.M1` because I need to add a new common functionality. Usually I would create a new abstract method and call it by the second *base* class like this:

```cs
abstract class C1
{
    public abstract void M1();
}

abstract class C2 : C1
{   
    // M1 should get a default implementation 
    // and then M1 in the next derived class should be called
    public override void M1()
    {
        // ...
        M1Internal();
    }

    protected abstract void M1Internal();
}

class Cx : C2
{
    protected override void M1Internal()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, I have over 20 such classes and updating them all is a lot of work so I was wondering if there is another way that would allow me to override `M1` in both `C2` and `Cx` and call them in this order `C1.M1()` then `Cx.M1()` without creating the new *intermediate* helper method. Is there any better pattern for such cases?

Comment: How are the classes `C1`, `C2` and `Cx` related? Who inherits who?

Comment: @MindSwipe oops, sorry, I forgot to add the inheritance. Fixed!

Comment: @John I could but this would mean adding the same code to all the other classes. I'd rather avoid this becasue it's easy to forget about it.

Comment: What do you mean by `// Other overriden members...` in C2? Is M1 being implemented in C2?

Comment: @MindSwipe I updated the code. Nope, `M1` has currently no default implementation but it should get one. Then the next `M1` should be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's best to use decorator pattern in this case. Use composition rather than inheritance if possible.

```
abstract class C1
{
    public abstract void M1();
}

class Cx : C1
{
    public override void M1()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class CxWithCommonBehavior : C1
{
    C1 realObject;

    public CxWithCommonBehavior(C1 realObject)
    {
        this.realObject = realObject;
    }

    public override void M1()
    {
        // common behavior
        realObject.M1();
    }
}
```

Note than you need only one CxWithCommonBehavior class for all derived Cx classes - you pass the decorated instance in the constructor.

This way you can add more behaviors, chain them in all possible ways and even add or remove them at runtime

Comment: I would need to adjust the architecture a little bit but I think this might be actually the most future-proof design.

Comment: Coool! I've checked how this would work with Autofac and its supports this natively so I can also automatically compose all these new compositions ;-)

Comment: In case someone else was looking for it: [decorators with Autofac](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators)

Answer (score 1):

What about simply calling `base.M1` at `Cx.M1`?

```
class Cx : C2
{
    protected override void M1()
    {
        base.M1();//i.e. C2.M1()
        //Cx.M1 internal logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is easy to forget and to automate. Especially in new classes but definitelly an option in smaller solutions.